# how can I use appscript in google sheets to record only rows that have had a change in one specific cell at the end of the day?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

With the attached copy [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QrNJhZPbEi0TJprMm7vUASP11FSKyUkLpOZAniRETNw/edit#gid=947327734), I want to have a record a history of all rows that have a change in column K at the end of the day from the start of the day.

[Data Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWVAh.png)

Checked couple sources using appscript but none was helpful

Comment: How would you define end of day and start of day? is it a problem if the user with write access to the spreadsheet can see and modify these values?

Comment: @medic17- You can access it; start is 00:00:00 and end if 23:59:59

Comment: How about an 'onEdit' trigger focused on Column K that writes a timestamp, plus old and new values to an "audit" sheet?